# Where can I find my NSCocoaErrorDomain description?

Tags: macos, cocoa

So I'm running a command line Swift tool to manage my dock.

The command `dockutil --remove #{appName}` works when doing it straight on the shell but when I execute it from within Swift I get this error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "(null)"
```

Fine enough. Except that when I check up the docs there is no useful information.

You can see for yourself here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscocoaerrordomain

Where would I be able to find this? Thinking to try a header file but not sure which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good documentation by Apple with all error codes (as far as I know), but there is a very useful site: [OSStatus.com](https://osstatus.com)

According to this site, code 3587 is only used once by Apple: [`NSExecutableLoadError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1448136-nserror_codes/nsexecutableloaderror?language=objc) in the Foundation framework.